# PLSQL Trigger To Record Update To Audit Table If Column_X Updates

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to keep an eye if a specific column in a table receives an update and if so to insert that change into my auditing table. I have been able to write this trigger to do that if ANY column changes, or if my column changes to a specific value but for some reason when I have tried comparing the old.column_x != new.column_x it is not recording the update. I've tried several variations of code, this is the latest I have attempted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_table
AFTER UPDATE ON table_1
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.column_x != old.column_x)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO audit_table (
    column_1,
    old_column_x,
    new_column_x,
    auditdtm
    )
VALUES (
    :old.column_1,
    :old.column_x,
    :new.column_x,
    SYSDATE); 
END
```

Comment: No it compiles without error. If I change the WHEN line to [WHEN (new.column_x IS NULL)] then the trigger works and records my updates when I null that column on a record.

Comment: do you expect column_x to be null?

Comment: Yes, a function in my application will set that column to either NULL or 01/01/3000.

Comment: Handle `null` case using an `or` condition in the `when` clause

Comment: Won't that insert a record into my audit table though even if column_x is not changed but another column in the source table is changed? That source table has changes on other columns frequently so I don't want to trigger an audit unless this specific column_x is changed.

Comment: the `null` case is to ensure that if a value changed to or from `null`, it'll be audited. Otherwise, the simple comparison will always return `false` if either old or new value is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Gurwinder Singh, I think this is what you were telling me to try. This works considering my data is always going to/from a NULL status, though there probably is a prettier way to write it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_table
AFTER UPDATE ON table_1
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ((new.column_x IS NULL AND old.column_x IS NOT NULL) OR (new.column_x IS NOT NULL AND old.column_x IS NULL))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO audit_table (
    column_1,
    old_column_x,
    new_column_x,
    auditdtm
    )
VALUES (
    :old.column_1,
    :old.column_x,
    :new.column_x,
    SYSDATE); 
END
```